# ReplaceImageValue and ReplacePixelValue extremely slow

Tags: image-processing, replacement, color

I have a grey scale image:

[image]

and I am doing the following:

```
bin = Binarize[image, 0.18]
```

[image]

```
pos = PixelValuePositions[bin, 1];
resultImage = ReplaceImageValue[bin, pos -> Red]
```

[image]

**The routine `ReplaceImageValue` is extremely slow, it takes 48 sec.**

In other languages likes Matlab or IDL this is done in less than a sec.

What is here the problem? The same is with `ReplacePixelValue`.

Thanks for your help.

PS: Is there a difference between `ReplaceImageValue` and `ReplacePixelValue`?

Comment: `Binarize[image, 0.18]` gives me a completely white image

Comment: If you just want to highlight pixels, you can use: `HighlightImage[image, bin]`, which is very fast. In general, working with coordinates/indices seems to be much slower than using converting images to arrays with `ImageData` and using simple arithmetic.

Comment: Hi belisarius, see above my binarized image ...
Thanks to nikie ... but it's really strange why it is so slow.

Comment: You've been in this site for two months and asked 7 questions. But you never answered one, never voted and never accepted an answer. Those things **are** important. Please see below for the typical welcome message and try to follow the suggestions!

Comment: Dear belisarius ... sorry I am new ... I have voted to all the usefull and very helpfull answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main culprit for the slowness is the presence of a couple of lines like this in the internal implementation of `ReplacePixelValue`:

```
coords = DeleteDuplicates[coords, {}];
```

I have not seen this usage of an empty list in the second argument of `DeleteDuplicates` and have no idea what it is supposed to do. It is very slow though. If we temporarily redefine `DeleteDuplicates` to avoid this problem the replacement is much faster:

```
Block[{DeleteDuplicates = #&}, ReplacePixelValue[img, pos -> Red]]
```

It is still not particularly quick, there is quite a bit of code for processing and validating coordinates and data types and so on. As others have said, it is faster to operate directly on the image data. Here's a simple example using `ReplacePart`:

```
Image @ ReplacePart[ImageData[img ~ColorConvert~ "RGB"], pos -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what I get in Mathematica 10.0.2:

```
In[1]:= img= Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/natsI.png"];
        bin=Binarize[img,0.18];
        AbsoluteTiming[pos=PixelValuePositions[bin,1];]
        AbsoluteTiming[resultImage=ReplacePixelValue[bin,pos->Red];]
Out[3]= {0.004004,Null}
Out[4]= {2.661534,Null}
```

The performance of `ReplacePixelValue` and `ReplaceImageValue` has been improved and in the next version of Mathematica the timings will be as follows:

```
In[1]:= img= Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/natsI.png"];
        bin=Binarize[img,0.18];
        AbsoluteTiming[pos=PixelValuePositions[bin,1];]
        AbsoluteTiming[resultImage=ReplacePixelValue[bin,pos->Red];]
Out[3]= {0.004004,Null}
Out[4]= {0.024023,Null}
```

In Mathematica 10.0.2, `ColorReplace` is faster than `PixelValuePositions` and `ReplacePixelValue`:

```
In[1]:= img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/natsI.png"];
        bin=Binarize[img,0.18];
        AbsoluteTiming[resultImage=ColorReplace[bin,White->Red];]
Out[3]= {0.155144,Null}
```

Comment: In the last sentence, you mean _faster than `ReplacePixelValue` but not than `PixelValuePositions`_?

Answer (score 5):

One way to speed things up is to get the `ImageData` and work with that directly.  A simple rule can give you your result:

```
Image[ImageData@bin /. {1 -> {1, 0, 0}, 0 -> {0, 0, 0}}]
```

This takes 0.1 seconds on my computer compared to 2 seconds for the `ReplacePixelValue` version.

Yes there is a difference between `ReplaceImageValue` and `ReplacePixelValue`.  Consider:

```
bin = Image[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}];
pos = PixelValuePositions[bin, 1];
Row[{bin, " ", ReplaceImageValue[bin, pos -> Red], " ", ReplacePixelValue[bin, pos -> Red]}]
```

[image: 1]

`ReplaceImageValue` uses an image coordinate system rather than pixel values.  You need to offset your pixel values by 0.5 to get the centre of a pixel.  Otherwise you land on a border between pixels and fill the neighbours too.  So what you probably want in `ReplacePixelValue`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your info ... also your first hint regarding ReplacePixelValue is very usefull

Answer (score 3):

To find a good binarization value, you can quickly scan through all the values. It's very quick.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/natsI.png"]
Manipulate[Binarize[img, t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

You can make it red this way:

```
z = ImageMultiply[img, 0]; Manipulate[ColorCombine[{Binarize[img, t], z, z}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I do not want to use ColorCombine because when I put a yellow pixel on top on a red pixel I want to see yellow and not a combined color ... this is the reason why I am working with positions.